# How to use one icon for the application and one for the activities?

Tags: android

I am building an Android app. In this app I have added a launcher icon (to be used as an app icon) but I also using another icon to be used in the actionbar on all activities. The activity icon got a transparent background color but the application icon is using a solid color background.

The problem is that when I install the app the application is using the activitity icon instead of the launcher icon. The problem with this is that the app icon get a transparent background color instead of a solid one.

What is wrong?

This is my manifest code for the application:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.example.dev.MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" >
```

This is the manifest code for one of the activities (the are all the same):

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.TasksDetailsActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_logo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tasks_details" >
        </activity>
```

The app is using the ic_menu_logo (transparent) instead of the ic_launcher (solid color) icon when installing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "android:icon".  Use "android:logo" instead:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.TasksDetailsActivity"
            android:logo="@drawable/ic_menu_logo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tasks_details" >
        </activity>
```